# How do I create this matrix with these conditions in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I would like to create a matrix `w_prev` from a matrix `wt` with these conditions.

1. wt is a `4x100` matrix.
2. w_prev is a `1x4*N` matrix with N being an integer. The first 4 rows of `w_prev` are the 4 elements in the first column of `wt`, second 4 rows of `w_prev` are the 4 elements of the second column of `wt` etc. until integer N.

In this example, N is 3 which works fine. k is 1 by the way.

```
w_prev=[wt(:,k);wt(:,k+1);wt(:,k+2)]
```

I would like to program it for generic integer N.

Comment: It would be good if you added a small example with input values and expected output so that people can copy, paste and check their solution.

Comment: OK I will do that next time. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @EOFF You can do it *this* time by [edit]ing your question!

Comment: @Wolfie Actually I slightly modified the code example by Daniel and it worked! So there is no need to edit the question this time!

Comment: @EOFF The detail you're missing is that this is a community Q&A - improving your question helps future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: @Wolfie Oh Yeah. OK!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the colon operator certain columns of the matrix. Here you want column k to k+2:

```
wt(:,k:k+2)
```

This already returns the right elements, but in the wrong shape. It's a 4x3. Use `reshape` to reshape it into a vector:

```
reshape(wt(:,k:k+2),[],1)
```

For generic N:

```
reshape(wt(:,k:k+N-1),[],1)
```

Comment: The OP asks for a result which is `1*4*N`, not `N*1` - I think you need to specify the dimensions differently in the `reshape`.

Comment: @Wolfie Actually all I had to do was w_prev=reshape(wt(:,k:k+N-1),[],1). And it worked!

Comment: @EOFF not sure why I forgot the version for generic N, had it still in my command window... Updated the answer.